# cat and "\b"funky character in external file

Tags: r, escaping, cat

I am attempting to cat homegrown LATEX output from R using cat but run into this snag that I suspect has to do with Encoding which I know nothing about or even where to start.

Using cat like this:

```
cat(paste0("\b", paste0(1, 2, "r")))
```

Produces exactly what I expect in the console.  But:

```
cat(paste0("\b", paste0(1, 2, "r")), file="foo.txt")
```

gives an odd square character where the "\b" was ([as seen HERE](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/61803503/foo.txt)).  I doubt this is a new problem for R/LATEX users creating home grown stuff but am obviously not searching with the right key words to find out an answer.

1. What is happening?
2. How do I fix it?

EDIT: Per Dason's suggestion:

```
> readLines("foo.txt")
[1] "\b 1 2 r"
```

Comment: Well, I learned something today.  I always thought `\b` meant the "bell" sound, but no -- it's backspace!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is wrong.  Your editor is displaying the square character in place of \b.  Try

```
readLines("foo.txt")
```

to see that "\b12r" is what is stored in the file.

Comment: Any way to make it a back space like `"\n"` becomes a next line?

Comment: @TylerRinker That's not an R issue, that's to do with your editor.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question above then because I need it to work properly regardless of the editor.  Actually I'm going to mark this thread as solved and open a new one.

Comment: @TylerRinker I guess I'm wondering what your motivation for this is.

Comment: Question asked at talkstats because it was suggested this is not really an R question: http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/29340-Maybe-this-not-need-escaped-quot-/b-quot